# Constrain proportion option in sorl-thumbnail

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

I have many images with arbitrary heights and widths ( 2033x1957, 1560X980, ...).
When i use sorl-thumbnail for these images in order to resize them to be 160x160 i don't get these exact sizes. I get images with sizes like 160x120, 120x160...
Is there a constrain proportion option(like in photoshop) in sorl-thumbnail in order to get the exact 160x160 size?

Comment: If you insist on 160x160, then images that aren't perfectly square will appear stretched! You probably just want to superimpose (and center) the images you're getting onto a transparent 160x160 background

Comment: He's asking if there's a way to keep the proportions (as in **not** stretched :P ) and yes it's called cropping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the `crop` option. this will use as much as possible of the source image and cut off slices at the sides to match the exact resolution you want while not stretching the image.

```
{% thumbnail myimage "160x160" crop="center" %}
```

see http://thumbnail.sorl.net/examples.html for more examples and optional parameters to `crop`